# Get IP address of the clients connected to Adobe's ams 5.x media server

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, fms3

How do I get IP address of the clients connected to Adobe's ams 5.x media server. Is there an admin API which can give me the details or How do I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Check FMS documentation about [Client.ip](http://help.adobe.com/en%5fUS/FlashMediaServer/3.5%5fSS%5fASD/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7ec3.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7fd2)